# disabling popups in about:config also disabled flash

Tags: firefox, popups

I disabled all popups in Firefox by going to about:config > dom.popup_allowed_events and removing everything. Unfortunately, now I have to allow Flash every time, which was not my intent. I didn't think it was a popup. How can I re-enable Flash? I set it to Always Activate in Plugins, but config seems to be overriding it. Also, Flash, when enabled, goes really slow then stops. I reset Firefox but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to enable Flash:

```
about:config => plugin.state.flash = 2
```

The flash plugin has 3 states:

- off is 0
- ask is 1
- on is 2

**References**

- [Mozillazine: Flash](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Flash)
- [Bugzilla: Don't store plugin preferences via pluginreg.dat: store them per-mimetype `(Flash plugin settings not kept when updating it)`
  (Java plugin reenabled randomly)`(All plugins reenabled when switching architectures on mac)`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=830267)